# encrypt file without creating a new one

Tags: openssl

I wrote a C program using openssl library to encrypt/decrypt files with AES. The problem is that I can't work on (read: encrypt) the **same** `file.rar`. Instead, all I can do is to create a new `file.rar.enc` then delete the original `file.rar`.

This way it’s possible to recover the original `file.rar` and – as a result – the encrypting process is really useless. Is there any way to operate in the same file during encryption/decryption?

Here is my C code :

```
  FILE *ifp = fopen(to_encrypt, "rb");
  FILE *ofp = fopen(new_name, "wb");
  int bytes_read, bytes_written, num=0;
  unsigned char indata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE], outdata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char skey[17],iv[] = "myIV";
  strcpy(skey, "myKey");  
  AES_KEY key;
  AES_set_encrypt_key(skey, 128, &key);

  while (1) {
    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, ifp);
    AES_cfb128_encrypt(indata, outdata, bytes_read, &key, iv, &num, AES_ENCRYPT);
    bytes_written = fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, ofp);
    if (bytes_read < AES_BLOCK_SIZE)   break;   
  }
```

Comment: Also see [Reliably Erasing Data From Flash-Based Solid State Drives](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~swanson/papers/Fast2011SecErase.pdf). Its especially important of phones and tablets, which often use memory cards rather than traditional disk drives. Even "in-place" or "in situ" encryption may leave data on the drive due to [wear leveling or write leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling).

Comment: What happens if you simply set the output file to the same file as the input file when encrypting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> in this way it's possible to recover the original file.rar, then the encrypting process is really useless.

Your statement here implies a particular use case.  Such encryption is not useless if you are sending the encrypted file.  The encryption is useless if it is intended to protect against some later system compromise (ex: a lost laptop).

In the event your system is compromised any encryption short of full disk encryption will not suffice and the original data will likely remain recoverable.

- Your operating system has swap (on disk) memory.
- Programs you might have used to read files contained in your now-encrypted rar-file might have made copies.
- Most printing involves a sequence of temporary files.
- Modern SSD drives do not really "delete" anything since writing to flash causes wear which negatively impacts the product lifetime.
- Moreover, modern flash has wear-leveling - that means over-writing a file almost never obliterates the previous data but instead writes the new data to a new block.

In each of the above cases there exists the original plaintext on your drive that can be forensically recovered.  You will not escape this situation just by making a C program that over-writes the previous file.

Comment: so there is no way to encrypt my files in order to protect them against some later system compromise.
but why encryption virus and ransomwares pose problems if the original files will still exist in the drive ?

Comment: @spesky It's a  matter of use case.  When data is locked away on ransom the user unconditionally wants _all_ of that data back and the (likely) only way to get all the data is to pay.  On the other hand, _some_ of the data can be recovered (often much of the data) through forensic means.  If you are encrypting for security you'd like or require _none_ of the data be recoverable.  In the ransom case it doesn't help that the forensics probably cost more than the ransom.

Comment: If you want to protect against future system compromise, your two practical options are full-disk encryption and encrypted mountable images, both of which prevent unencrypted data from ever actually being written to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can encrypt files: simply *map the file to memory* and encrypt blocks of data. Store the optional IV / authentication tag at the end of the file or you may not be able to encrypt in place.

As Thomas already mentioned, you may run into problems with SSD's, where it is very likely that you may not write over the original file. However, the SSD could delete the block depending on the implementation. Actually, hard disks could do the same, but usually they only do such a thing if a sector is marked bad.

That said, you'd still be protected against persons that cannot directly access the device itself. You could combine it with SSD encryption to offer additional protection (this also makes it easy to destroy the data on SSD: the SSD can basically just destroy the data encryption key).

Comment: Probably the worst they can do is to hack the SSD firmware.